# Apache2 + Ubuntu + Mono: Issue with System.Web.ActiveDirectoryProvider

Tags: .net, apache, ubuntu, active-directory, mono

Apache2 + Ubuntu + Mono: Issue with System.Web.ActiveDirectoryProvider

When my web application trys to use Active Directory Authentication I get the following: [Web Page Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd5qM.png)

When I look at the logs under `/var/log/apache2/error.log` I have this:

```
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:31.160499 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17187:tid 140082060339072] AH00491: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
mod-mono-server received a shutdown message
Invalid type System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatter for instance field System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeFormatterMatch:<Formatter>k__BackingField
Invalid type System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext for instance field System.Web.Http.Filters.HttpActionExecutedContext:_actionContext
Invalid type System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionDescriptor for instance field System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpParameterDescriptor:_actionDescriptor
Invalid type System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext for instance field System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatedEventArgs:<ActionContext>k__BackingField
Invalid type System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext for instance field System.Web.Http.Validation.ModelValidatingEventArgs:<ActionContext>k__BackingField
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.263821 2017] [so:warn] [pid 17361] AH01574: module mono_module is already loaded, skipping
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.268918 2017] [:error] [pid 17366:tid 140510323828608] Failed running '/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2 --filename /tmp/mod_mono_server_global --nonstop --master (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)'. Reason: No such file or directory
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.272467 2017] [:error] [pid 17370:tid 140510323828608] Failed running '/usr/bin/mod-mono-server2 --filename /tmp/mod_mono_server_global --nonstop --master (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null) (null)'. Reason: No such file or directory
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.273501 2017] [:error] [pid 17362:tid 140510323828608] Not running mod-mono-server.exe because no MonoApplications, MonoApplicationsConfigFile or MonoApplicationConfigDir specified.
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.274003 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 17362:tid 140510323828608] AH00489: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) mod_mono/3.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jan 27 10:14:33.274016 2017] [core:notice] [pid 17362:tid 140510323828608] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
Listening on: /tmp/mod_mono_server_beta.medialabstage.com
Root directory: /var/www/beta.medialabstage.com/
root@int-p-pdm1:/home/mladmin#
```

Any idea what is going on? I have used different DLLs for system.web.dll from .NET package and the windows Mono package.